# The property '$YourPropertyHere' could not be created from it's default value. Error message: Could not find a part of the path %temp%

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Situation:
A windows service (running under the Local System account) started to crash on de clients server. It had been running without issue for months.
The error we saw in the EventLog was:

> Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17965, time
>   stamp: 0x506dcae6 
>   Exception code: 0xe0434352

After some searching we came to the conclusion that this meant nothing except that our windows service had crashed with an unhandled exception. Luckily our windows service logs all exceptions. In our log file we found this:

> The property '--removed--' could not be created from it's default value. Error message: Could not find a part of the path 'S:\TEMP\byvqti2p.tmp'.
>           Source: System
>           StackTrace:    at

```
System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyValue.Deserialize()
   at System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyValue.get_PropertyValue()
   at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.get_Item(String propertyName)
   at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.get_Item(String propertyName)
```

Comment: When posting a self-answered question, please post the answer as an actual answer, not in the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the problem is the server doesn't have a S: drive. Maybe it once did, but we don't really know.

As a test we tried to run the windows service under our account. That worked!

So the problem is linked to the Local System account. And here comes the solution:

Open the Enviroment Variables screen. Look under System variables and located "TEMP" and/or "TMP". This is where we found "S:\Temp". We changed it to "C:\Temp" and just like that the windows service was running again under Local System.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, although from launching the program via RDP (not launching as a service).  The error message was:

`The property 'YourPropertyHere' could not be created from it's default value. Error message: Could not find a part of the path. 'C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Temp\2\ymapg21h.tmp'.`

(note - the incorrect spelling *it's* occurred in the message, not a typo by me).

The directory `C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Temp\2` does not exist, and this is the value of `%TEMP%` and `%TMP%`. So it seems like a bug in .NET that attempting to initialize a property from the `AppName.config` file throws an exception and fails if `%TEMP%` does not exist.

The exact code in my app that threw the exception was:

```
var list = Properties.Settings.Default.YourPropertyHere.Cast<string>().ToList();
```

and the property was a `StringCollection`. The problem did not occur for a `string` property .

---

Raymond Chen talks about the reasons for the number on the end of `%TEMP%` in https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110125-00/?p=11673 . One workaround as described in that article is to disable the feature whereby the number is added to the end of `%TEMP%` via group policy editor.

The workaround I used was to put the following code inside `Main()` just before the `Application.Run` call (C#; and needs `using System.IO;`)

```
try
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetTempPath());
}
catch(Exception)
{ }
```